# A weird title bar appears along with the Intent chooser window

Tags: android, android-theme

When I click a hyper link in my app a "intent chooser window" appears along with app suggestions. Along with that a Title bar with my app name overlays my Action bar.

I am using the following themes as Base theme.

default -- @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar.

v14 ----   @style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

I have attached a screen shot for reference.

In that I have highlighted the title bar in red color. 
Kindly suggest me on how to remove this.

[image]